# How to resolve missing class org.slf4j.helpers.MarkerIgnoringBase when building Kuali Student

Tags: kuali

When building Kuali Student from https://github.com/kuali-student/ks-development using the command `mvn -skipTests=true -Dmaven.failsafe.skip=true clean install` I recieve the following error:

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] KS DB .............................................. SUCCESS [  7.816 s]
[INFO] KS DB Validation ................................... SUCCESS [  0.573 s]
[INFO] KS Impex ........................................... SUCCESS [  0.080 s]
[INFO] KS LUM Rice ........................................ SUCCESS [  6.436 s]
[INFO] KS LUM UI Common ................................... SUCCESS [  1.885 s]
[INFO] KS LUM Program ..................................... SUCCESS [  1.785 s]
[INFO] KS LUM UI .......................................... SUCCESS [  2.505 s]
[INFO] KS Enroll UI ....................................... FAILURE [  0.502 s]
[INFO] KS CM KRAD ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] KS Security ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] KS Standard Security ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] KS Security Token Service .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] KS Common Kitchen Sink ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] KS Common Web ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] KS Curriculum Management Deployment Resources ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] KS Enroll Deployment Resources ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] KS Enroll Rice ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] KS Web ............................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] KS with Rice Bundled ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] KS with Rice Embedded .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] KS Rice Standalone ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] KS Metro ........................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] KS Eclipselink Pom ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 23.640 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-11-04T08:15:37-10:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 148M/850M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.16:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) on project ks-enroll-ui: Execution install node and npm of goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.16:install-node-and-npm failed: A required class was missing while executing com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.16:install-node-and-npm: org/slf4j/helpers/MarkerIgnoringBase
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.16
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/j/m2/ks-development/com/github/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/0.0.16/frontend-maven-plugin-0.0.16.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/j/m2/ks-development/com/github/eirslett/frontend-plugin-core/0.0.16/frontend-plugin-core-0.0.16.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/j/m2/ks-development/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.13/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/j/m2/ks-development/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.13/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/j/m2/ks-development/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.5/commons-compress-1.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/j/m2/ks-development/org/tukaani/xz/1.2/xz-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/j/m2/ks-development/commons-io/commons-io/1.3.2/commons-io-1.3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/j/m2/ks-development/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.1/httpclient-4.3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/j/m2/ks-development/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.3/httpcore-4.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/j/m2/ks-development/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/j/m2/ks-development/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/j/m2/ks-development/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.10/plexus-utils-3.0.10.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/j/m2/ks-development/javax/enterprise/cdi-api/1.0/cdi-api-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/j/m2/ks-development/javax/annotation/jsr250-api/1.0/jsr250-api-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/j/m2/ks-development/com/google/guava/guava/10.0.1/guava-10.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/j/m2/ks-development/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/j/m2/ks-development/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/3.1.0/sisu-guice-3.1.0-no_aop.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/j/m2/ks-development/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/j/m2/ks-development/org/eclipse/sisu/org.eclipse.sisu.inject/0.0.0.M2a/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.0.0.M2a.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/j/m2/ks-development/asm/asm/3.3.1/asm-3.3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/j/m2/ks-development/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/j/m2/ks-development/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.2/maven-plugin-annotations-3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/j/m2/ks-development/com/googlecode/slf4j-maven-plugin-log/slf4j-maven-plugin-log/1.0.0/slf4j-maven-plugin-log-1.0.0.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[project>org.kuali.student:student:2.1.1-FR2-M1-SNAPSHOT, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.slf4j.helpers.MarkerIgnoringBase
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appears to be related to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5787 which has been fixed for Maven 3.3.8 (not yet released at the time of this writting).  One of the comments suggests using Maven 3.2.5 as a work around which resolved this error for me.